# In Windows Phone 7 how can I save a BitmapImage to local storage?

Tags: caching, windows-phone-7

In Windows Phone 7 how can I save a BitmapImage to local storage? I need to save the image for caching and reload if it is requested again in the next few days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you save the file into IsolatedStorage you can set a relative path to view it from there.

Here's a quick example saving a file that was included in the XAP (as a resource) into Isolated Storage.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
  if (!isoStore.FileExists(fileName)
  {
    var sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative));

    using (var br = new BinaryReader(sr.Stream))
    {
      byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)sr.Stream.Length);
      string strBaseDir = string.Empty;
      const string DelimStr = "/";
      char[] delimiter = DelimStr.ToCharArray();
      string[] dirsPath = fileName.Split(delimiter);

      // Recreate the directory structure
      for (int i = 0; i < dirsPath.Length - 1; i++)
      {
          strBaseDir = Path.Combine(strBaseDir, dirsPath[i]);
          isoStore.CreateDirectory(strBaseDir);
      }

      using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(isoStore.CreateFile(fileName)))
      {
          bw.Write(data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may also be interested in the image caching converters created by [Ben Gracewood](http://www.ben.geek.nz/2010/07/one-time-cached-images-in-windows-phone-7/) and [Peter Nowaks](http://blogs.compactframework.de/Peter.Nowak/2010/08/12/ldquoIntelligentrdquo+Image+Caching+For+WP+7.aspx).  They both show saving images into isolated storage and loading them from there.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I've used is to pass the stream you retrieve for the image in your xap straight into an isolated storage file. Not a lot of moving parts.

```
        using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {

            var bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.SetSource(picStreamFromXap);
            var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bi);

            using (var isoFileStream = isoStore.CreateFile("pic.jpg")) 
                Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, isoFileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

        }
```

Comment: sadly this only works for JPG files and not for other media types.